# Is there a way to get information about a module at read time?

Tags: racket

I've since this summer played around with making a toy language in Racket. Every form has a fixed arity and by default applies so parentheses are not needed. eg. `+` has arity 2 so `+ 3 + 4 5` is `(+ 3 (+ 4 5))` and `+ + 3 4 5` is `(+ (+ 3 4) 5)`.

To do this I'm storing in the main module the symbols and their arity. The reader doesn't care if it's a special form or procedure, but is there a better way to do this using features from racket? Thus I can import a module metadata and query that instead during parsing?

Comment: Hi.  "The reader doesn't care if it's a ..." what's the "it" referring to?
Storing meta-data is often be done in a submodule (but I am a bit unsure where (and when!) you want to use the meta-information.

Comment: @soegaard a symbol in the reader, becomes an identifier in the resulting syntax. If I were to make new syntax for racket/base, could I lookup `'cons` somehow in racket/base to find it's arity?

Comment: Have you written your own reader or are you reusing the builtin one?

Comment: @soegaard My own, but I use racket `read-syntax` in mine. To fix it now I have a hash of symbols represented with number of arguments it takes so it reads that many times and in the end  do `(datum->syntax (cons op args))` so `+ + + 1 2 3 4` becomes `(+ (+ (+ 1 2) 3) 4)` "magically". I know the system complaints eventually if `+` wouldn't exist but not how accessible/far down that happens. The idea is to loose the hash.

Comment: I have added a way to get from a symbol to an arity.

Comment: If you could do the arity stuff at macro-expansion time (with a `#%module-begin` macro), you might be able to get more accurate binding arity information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to go from symbol to arity.

```
#lang racket

(define base-ns (make-base-namespace))
(define (symbol->arity s)  
  (parameterize ([current-namespace base-ns])
    (procedure-arity (namespace-variable-value s))))

(symbol->arity 'cons)
```

Comment: Very nice. If I were only to look in just one particular modules, like `racket/list` how would I make a namespace that only had that?

Comment: Use make-empty-namespace to create the namespace. Then use namespace-require to require the module.

Comment: Thats what I tried, but it failed miserably, however I found [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/mk-namespace.html) that  `make-base-empty-namespace` would be the correct option. Seems like this weekend will be all about namespaces. Thanks :)

Comment: This will be a very crude approximation if you have to do this at read-time. There might be a macro that expands to a `require` form and introduces an identifier with a different arity, shadowing the old one. If you could do the arity stuff at macro-expansion time (with a `#%module-begin` macro), you might be able to get more accurate binding arity information.

Comment: @AlexKnauth For now I think I'm good as the surface syntax won't support `require` but I think if I ever get support for it I'll just add to the namespace with `namespace-require` as I go. Wouldn't that work?